# How can I generate the difference between 2 commits which ignore spaces

Tags: git, version-control, diff

In my git log, I have 2 commits. How can I generate the difference - ignoring spaces - between them?

```
$ git log
commit e5640171f391fdf479fa14fab0da6628efed1fa6
Author: test <test@mycompany.com>
Date:   Mon Jul 13 11:41:02 2009 -0700

    Fix Bug 1.

commit 0984e27b75f480da8b8c4ce2399bf877c557a78d
Author: test <test@mycompany.com>
Date:   Tue Jul 7 14:50:26 2009 -0700

    Fix Bug 2.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
git diff --ignore-all-space 0984 e564
```

-w is shorthand for --ignore-all-space

More important is knowing how I found out:

```
git help diff
```

This allowed me to see the various options with explanations.

Answer (score 2):

Simply:

```
git diff -w 0984e27 e56401
```

Comment: Thank you. But where do you get the number "0984e27 ", "e56401" from?

Comment: They're the hashes for your two commits, as in your question. You can use any unambiguous prefix for commit hashes instead of the whole thing.